# Why isn't Post Type Templates working for me?

Tags: wordpress

So, [according to this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates), it states:

> single-{post_type}.php
>       If your custom post type were 'product', and/or query_var = "product", WordPress would look for single-product.php to display the
>   single or permalink of the post.

So I have this code in my functions.php:

```
register_post_type( 'project',$args);
```

And I have this template: `single-project.php`

Then why isn't my custom post using this template?

**update**
Using `get_post_types()` I can see that my post type is not listed. If it is not registered, then why can I create and delete custom posts?

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','init_setup');

function init_setup() {
  add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
}

function create_post_type() {
  $args = array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => __( 'Prosjekter' ),
      'singular_name' => __( 'Prosjekt' ),
      'add_new' => __('Nytt prosjekt')
    ),
    'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'taxonomies' => array('category'),
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes','post_tag' ),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'prosjekt')
  );

  register_post_type( 'project',$args);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Codex:

> register_post_type should only be invoked through the 'init' action.
>   It won't work at all if called before 'init', and aspects of the new
>   post type will work incorrectly if called later.

Have you tried registering it like so?

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' ); // NOT inside `init_setup()`
```

**[edit]**

The only other thing I can think of is that since you're using `rewrite`, you might want to flush the rewrite rules.  Also from the Codex:

> Note: If registering a post type inside of a plugin, call
>   flush_rewrite_rules() in your activation and deactivation hook (see
>   Flushing Rewrite on Activation below). If flush_rewrite_rules() is not
>   used, then you will have to manually go to Settings > Permalinks and
>   refresh your permalink structure before your custom post type will
>   show the correct structure.

If you don't want to fiddle with the `flush_rewrite_rules()` function at this moment, just go into Settings > Permalinks and re-save your permalink preferences.

Comment: @Steven I updated my answer with a different possible solution

Comment: Brilliant. I removed the re-write and set Permalink to 'Post name' and now it works. Thanks :-D

Comment: @Steven Great! Have fun.